# How to use animate.css animations with Vue's Transition and TransitionGroup components

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, vuejs3, animate.css

Vue has the v-if and v-for directives which create/remove the element in the DOM depending on the condition. To animate v-if and v-for, you have to use the Transition and TransitionGroup built-in components respectively. How can I use animate.css's built-in animations with these Vue built-in components?

Example;

```
<script setup lang="ts">
import { ref } from "vue";

const isModalVisible = ref<boolean>(false);
</script>
```

```html
<button @click="() => (isModalVisible = true)">Click Me<button>

<Transition name="I want an animate.css animation here">
    <Modal v-if="isModalVisible" />
</Transition>
```

Comment: Have a look at the think [VueUse/Motion](https://motion.vueuse.org/) If you don't find any good solution to use animate.css you can use VueUse/Motion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `<Transition>` component accepts props to override which class to apply, instead of generate ones from the given `name`. (See [documentation](https://vuejs.org/api/built-in-components.html#transition))

```html
<Transition
  enterActiveClass="animate__animated animate__bounce"
>
  <Modal v-if="isModalVisible" />
</Transition>
```

Example in [playground](https://sfc.vuejs.org/#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)